# Got achievement notification before reaching the milestone

Tags: bug, design

When I logged in today my Achievements listed that I just reached the 1K milestone (edits, etc.), when I actually have 993 reps:

[image]

Doing some further tests, if I attempt to edit it indicates that it will be placed on a review queue, suggesting that the privileges have *not* been given yet.

**Any ideas why this behavior appears?**

I have not visibly lost any rep recently (as to fall below the milestone again).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrectly informed of gaining a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224022/254466), [Reputation/Privileges Inconsistencies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196944/254466), [Privilege banner buggy? Or am I just confused?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72270/254466), and [Bug in rep calculation when displaying privileges banner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69982/254466)

Comment: To summarize the linked posts: There are actions that affect your reputation but do not appear in your history. By design, the system generates an alert when you gain a privilege, but generates no alert when you lose one. In every case I found where a developer stepped in to investigate, the developer declared that indeed reputation was lost and the behavior was by design.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your reputation history, it is likely that you had the reputation and then lost 7 rep. If you try to edit a question at this point it would be a suggested edit. One quick way to test that is to try and edit a post on meta as it does not allow suggested edits.

I looked at your profile and it shows the next privilege you are going to get is the edit questions and answers so I am guessing you got the rep for the privilege and then lost the rep.

Comment: Like I said in the post, I have *not* lost any rep recently. Also, losing 7 reps exactly is unlikely, as Downvotes take 2 (can't reach -7, unless if I downvoted which is -1).

Comment: Yes you have and this issue has been reported many times on other stack exchange sites and it always turns out that reputation was lost after the privilege was earned. Also did you check your profile to see what the next privilege you will gain is?

Comment: It is possible to lose rep when a post or user is deleted, and that loss is not reported in the rep tracker. And you wouldn't have had to lose exactly 7 rep to reach the point you see. You might have lost 10 for example, which would be accounted for by a vote or two.

Comment: @murgatroid99 actually when a user is deleted you get the -X indicator saying "User was deleted"... what I suspect is that I got an UV and then the caster undid the UV, perhaps creating this bug (somewhere I had 1003 but really had 993)